# Store all the debugging done in gdb in a file

Tags: c, debugging, unix, gdb

if i want to store all the actions that i have done in ***gdb*** on ***unix*** machine while debugging a ***c*** code what should i do.
for example:

i have attached a process to ***gdb*** and i have run it.later i have done some check in  some functions and verified some local variables etc.

If i want to store all the stuff that i have performed using ***gdb*** in a text file on ***unix***,what should i do?

Answer (score 4):

You can log all `gdb` output into a file (see the [manual](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Logging-Output.html)):

```
(gdb) set logging file <file>
(gdb) set logging on
(gdb) show logging
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `script` command, which "makes a typescript of everything printed on your terminal." That includes output from `gdb`, though.

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to start a flame war here, but Emacs has a gdb mode (the Grand Unified Debugger mode) and you can save any Emacs buffer to a file. If you use a different editor, it may also have a debugging plugin that works with gdb.

Comment: It's funny how an Emacs user expects to start a flame war by just mentioning that editor :)